# Jquery append line break

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic select change option used jquery append the option.
I need to add many option list. However I get error when I put line break between.

```
$("#country").change(function(){
    switch($("#country").val()){
        case "usa":$("#state").append("<option value='AL'>Alabama</option><option value='CA'>California</option>...");break         
        case "aus":$("#state").append("..");break...    
    }
});
```

I got error when I put line break between,is any way to solve this problem, because I need to add many option list. it's very hard to edit without the line break.

```
case "usa":$("#state").append("
    <option value='AL'>Alabama</option>
    <option value='CA'>California</option>...
");break
```

Comment: You really should fetch your data from a json object or server side, doing it like this will be horrible to maintain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the line break in the string, see: [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

```
case "usa":$("#state").append(" \
    <option value='AL'>Alabama</option> \
    <option value='CA'>California</option>... \
");break
```